# Can't see British Pound in currency switch Magento 2.2.2

Tags: currency

I have Magento 2.2.2 with multi store view, My base currency is Euro, seconde USD and I added British Pound, the problem I can't see the British Pound in the dropdown switch for currency choice I deleted the cache,  same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved,

Stores -> Currency -> Currency Rates, the value for GBP was empty, I manually added the Currency rate so it works.